# How to add a fork repository to "s.dependency" attribute in .podspec file of a CocoaPod?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoapods, afnetworking-2

I have been working on a AFNetworking forked repository and wants to add to my private pod. I am doing something like this.

```
s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.3' , :git => 'https://github.com/Codigami/AFNetworking.git', :commit => '9f9f4fe5b5959e0f2ea89e472eccf7aea6f37eea'
```

While doing

```
pod install
```

in terminal I am getting

```
[!] Invalid `ios-authentication-pod.podspec` file: [!] Unsupported version requirements. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.
```

on the other hand I tried to add this in a new project podfile using this.

```
pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/Codigami/AFNetworking.git', :commit => '9f9f4fe5b5959e0f2ea89e472eccf7aea6f37eea'
```

This works.
I didn't able to understand what the issue in above case?

Answer (score 1):

http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency
there is no :git and :commit options in podspec dependency specifier. You might be able to create your own private spec repo and put AFNetworking podspec there pointing with `s.source` to specific location.

Comment: So finally what have to write in.podspec file after creating own private spec repo and putting AFNetworking podspec there?

Comment: its not working still pointing to the public repository instead of forked one.

Comment: You need to force cocoapods to use your version of podspec if names are equal. This could be done by naming your repo with letter that goes before 'M', for ex repo named 'AMyPrivateRepo' should do the work

Comment: Yes, naming pod AAFNetworking and specifying it as dependency in podspec should work well

Comment: Anybody think like me and think this is just uggggly? I.e., having to do a naming workaround to use your local fork of a repo.

Comment: And just to be clear, we are talking about renaming just the .podspec file, right?